# How to prevent characters in Bootstrap datepicker text box from firebug?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Here i have a text box which generates dates from Bootstrap date-picker, and working very well.

But whenever user tries to change their value from firebug, then its changed..!

**Something like this:**

[image]

**Changed value**

[image]

I want to prevent this. but how?

Comment: do u have code in jsfiddle ?

Comment: no. not right now?

Comment: then please do it. it would easy for us to fix it.

Comment: Code on the client can be manipulated like this, there's no way to make sure the client does not modify it, that's why we never trust data coming from the client.

Comment: @Princesodhi here is fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0sryxtzq/

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: i am using Codeigniter framework

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to control the code when is on the client-side, so we can't prevent the user edits the input like he wants with firebug or another browser inspector.

That's why we **should** validate any single piece of data that comes from the client on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't.

Code inspectors are designed for debugging HTML and Javascript. They do so by showing the live DOM object of the web page. That means it reveals HTML code of everything you see on the page, even if they're generated by Javascript. Some inspectors even shows the code inside iframes.